# Why wont the Assertions validate my Symfony form?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to create a form with a bound DTO. I assert three attributes the DTO:

- $firstName
- $lastName
- $image

One should only be asserted when I create a new object. The remaining two should always be asserted.

**DTO**

```
class MyDTO
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private ?string $firstName;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private ?string $lastName;

    /**
     * @Assert\Image()
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={MyFormType::VALIDATION_NEW})
     */
    private ?UploadedFile $image;
...
```

**FormType**

```
class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    const VALIDATION_NEW = "new";

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        //TODO: Assertion doesnt work
        $builder->
            add('firstName', TextType::class, [
                'required' => false
            ])
            ->add('lastName', TextType::class, [
                'required' => false
            ])
            ->add('image', FileType::class, [
                'required' => false,
            ]);
    }
```

**Controller**

```
/**
     * @Route(path="/{myData}/edit", name="app.data.update")
     */
    public function edit(MyData $myData, Request $request)
    {
        $dtoData = MyDTO::fromEntity($myData);
        $form = $this->createForm(
            MyFormType::class,
            $dtoData,
            [
                'validation_groups' => [
                    MyFormType::VALIDATION_NEW
                ],
            ]
        );
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $this->repositoryClass->persist($dtoData->toEntity($myData));
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app.data.show');
        }

        return $this->render('app.edit.html.twig',
        [
            'myDataForm' => $form->createView()
        ]);
```

But even when I keep all fields blank, there are no messages about validation. The form allows me to save an empty form. I looked into the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html) but cant seem to find an answer. Why wont the assertions validate my form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but adding "Default" to the validation groups should solve the problem.

```
/**
 * @Route(path="/{myData}/edit", name="app.data.update")
 */
public function edit(MyData $myData, Request $request)
{
    $dtoData = MyDTO::fromEntity($myData);
    $form = $this->createForm(
        MyFormType::class,
        $dtoData,
        [
            'validation_groups' => [
                MyFormType::VALIDATION_NEW,
                'Default'
            ],
        ]
    );
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $this->repositoryClass->persist($dtoData->toEntity($myData));
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app.data.show');
    }

    return $this->render('app.edit.html.twig',
    [
        'myDataForm' => $form->createView()
    ]);
```

By adding this option the Validator should take into consideration the assertions specified in the entity

Comment: Thank you! That actually solved the problem. To be honest, I am a little shocked that the "default" option is not set by... well, default. If you have explicitly set the default option, then its not a default option.

Comment: I don't quite agree with you, if you add a custom validator, you may not need the default validator.